# how to secure war file in apache tomcte server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, hosting

I am developing web application using eclipse and I create a .war file and hosted into the tomcat server webapps folder.now I need to secure my hosted .war file because if any one opens the webapps folder.it shows all my content with in the .war file.how can I secure my hosted content in tomcat server. I am new to hosting process. can any one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "anyone opens the webapps folder"? On server side (i.e. ssh) or via URL (i.e. directory index listing)?

Comment: @Stefan i host the application in client system.i need client access the application but they don't see the source file.that's my need